# GitHub additional contribution/commit after amending last commit message

Tags: git, github

Well, I have changed my last commit message with `git commit --amend`, which I have already published on GitHub. Then I have pushed it again with `--force` and found out that I have an extra contribution. It seems to be okay, but in "Contribution activity" now I have:

Created X+1 commits in 1 repository

While in repository itself I see only X commits in that day. So the question is: Does an extra commit really exist (in history or somewhere else) and Can I refresh that information or it is just a feature of GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a minor issue with GitHub that I've encountered before. It will automatically be corrected when your user contributions are recalculated. If for some reason it isn't, and you care enough to have it corrected, contact GitHub. They've always been super responsive to me, and can trigger a recalculation by hand.

Edit: I've found the responses to emails I've sent before (not specific to amends, but I imagine it's similar)

> I've just triggered a rebuild on your contributions. This will ensure that your profile is accurately reflecting the commits that exist on GitHub and are currently linked to your account. This rebuild can take up to 24 hours, so let us know if you're still not seeing the correct numbers in 24 hours.

.

> Thanks for reaching out! Duplicate commits often show up after rebasing, but they should disappear after another push if the graph isn't manually rebuilt (which I've just done).
>
> If you're still seeing an unexpected number of contributions, please send us a link to the repository and we'll take another look!

Based on those two responses (to separate contacts), it look like you'll have to [contact GitHub](https://github.com/contact).

Comment: @Aleksei I'd suggest contacting them in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I asked a question, because I concerned that I am doing reseting/rebasing/amending incorrectly.

Comment: @Aleksei Can you include some more info in your question? I've based my answer on the little you've provided.

Comment: In fact, I think you have fully answered the question, but here is the complete information. 1) I've amend commit with `git commit --amend -m "New message"`2) Then I pushed it with `git push --force origin master` 3) As a result  I see a redundant commit. I've also experimented with resetting/rebasing:  `git reset --hard 30f3d`, `git push --force origin master` and a result was the same.